# Populus cannot deploy contract related to estimated gas is not enough error

Tags: out-of-gas, gas-estimate, populus

I am using [populus](http://populus.readthedocs.io).

- Platform darwin -- Python 2.7.12, pytest-3.0.2, py-1.4.31,
  pluggy-0.3.1
- Plugins: populus-1.1.0
- OS: Mac OS X

I do face with following error: for the following line on my test.py file.

```
my_contract       = unmigrated_chain.get_contract('Array');
```

In order to deploy my contract there is not enough gas.

```
    def test_token_contract_1(web3, accounts, unmigrated_chain):
>   my_contract       = unmigrated_chain.get_contract('Array');

    tests/test.py:7:
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/populus/chain.py:614: in get_contract
    kwargs=deploy_kwargs,
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/web3/contract.py:194: in deploy
    txn_hash = cls.web3.eth.sendTransaction(deploy_transaction)
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/web3/eth.py:216: in sendTransaction
    transaction=formatted_transaction,
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/web3/utils/transactions.py:25: in get_buffered_gas_estimate
    gas_estimate = web3.eth.estimateGas(gas_estimate_transaction)
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/web3/utils/functional.py:22: in inner
    value = fn(*args, **kwargs)
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/web3/eth.py:247: in estimateGas
    return self.request_manager.request_blocking("eth_estimateGas", [transaction])
```

For example when I remove a line from my contract my code works perfectly fine. But when I add a new line that does some computation, which leads my contract to exceed the estimated gas and gives the error I mentioned.

[Q] Due to out of gas problem I can't deploy my contract inside Populus. How can I over come this problem?

Please note that I was not able to do `import` my library .sol file in my contract file so one library and additional three contract is embedded into the same `Array.sol` file.

Thank you for your valuable time and help.

Comment: can you open up an issue on github for this and I can try to help you trouble shoot it: https://github.com/pipermerriam/populus/issues

Comment: I opened an issue as you guided. https://github.com/pipermerriam/populus/issues/221 . I did my best to explain the problem I have faced, please let me know if you need any additional information. @PiperMerriam. Thank you!